# Create Shortcut in flavor of F1 for "Show help for current function"

Tags: r, rstudio

In RStudio, I am using some functions like head() pretty often and I asked myself, if it's possible to make a shortcut like F1 (Help for current function) but as e.g. CTRL+y (head() for current data.frame).

Further explanation about F1: 
(F1 - shortcut) If you go to a function-name in your skript and press the F1 button you instantly get the help-informations about this function.

So my goal is to make a shortcut, s.t. if I click on a dataframe and press the shortcut, I get an output shown in the console like e.g. head(current.data.frame)

Thanks

Comment: I assume this is specifically for Rstudio? What exactly would determine the "current" data.frame?

Comment: Let me know if this answers your question, if you are using Rstudio (not sure if it works without), is using `View(current.data.frame)`. Then the tab this opens, gets automatically updated when the data is changed, and you can move it wherever you want...

Comment: @HectorHaffenden actually that would be a solution, if you work with only one data.frame. But if you work with multiple ones it's a littlebit time consuming to work with the View() function. Also head() is way faster in presenting data

Comment: @MrFlick yeah its for Rstudio, thanks. I also added further expllanations. Hope its more clear what I mean

Comment: Take a look at [RStudio Addins](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudioaddins/#overview). You can use them to execute R functions interactively and can control them with keyboard shortcuts. I've never used them myself and you might have to write the code yourself, but this seems like exactly what you're looking for

Comment: @divibisan I think, I can find a solution to my problem on that page. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you do solve your problem, post a self-answer explaining how you did it (and showing some example code you used)! I bet there are lots of people out there who would be interested in this but don't know this exists (I didn't either until I started looking into it for this question)

Comment: @divibisan I wanted to do so. I think it's a good idea and to make use of that can save some time in daily tasks. Right now I just want to finish some code and go to sleep. It's 00:17pm here